# Python: Strategically go through ten digit numbers with 0-9

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, digits

Recently, I read a math problem inspiring me to write a program. It asked to **arrange the digits 0-9 once each so that *xx xxx / xx xxx = 9*.** I wrote a python program to find the solutions and had a bit of trouble making sure the digits were different. I found a way using nested *whiles* and *ifs*, but I'm not quite happy with it.

```
b,c,x,y,z = 0,0,0,0,0  #I shortened the code from b,c,d,e,v,w,x,y,z
for a in range (10):
    while b < 10:
        if b != a:
            while c < 10:
                if c != b and c != a:
                    while x < 10:
                        if x != c and x != b and x != a:
                            while y < 10:
                                if y != x and y != c and y != b and y != a:
                                    while z < 10:
                                        if z != y and if z != z and y != c and z != b and z != a:
                                            if (a*100 + b*10 + c)/(x*100 + y*10 + z) == 9:
                                                print ()
                                                print (str (a*100 + b*10 + c) + "/" + str (x*100 + y*10 + z)
                                        z += 1
                                    z = 0
                                y += 1
                            y,z = 0,0
                        x += 1
                    x,y,z = 0,0,0
                c += 1
            c,x,y,z = 0,0,0,0
        b += 1
    b,c,x,y,z = 0,0,0,0,0
```

As you can see, the **code is very long and repetitive**, even the shortened form. Running it on my laptop **takes almost a minute** (and my laptop is new). I have searched for answers, but I only found ways to generate random numbers. I tried using *itertools.permutations* as well, but that only shows the permutations, not creating a number.

Generating all ten digits takes too long, and I want to know if there is a ***faster, simpler way, with an explanation, using python 3.***.

Thanks

Comment: Never seen a so nested code lol. Anyway I doubt there's a significant more performant way of implementing it, assuming it's implemented correctly. Note, your code is taking more time also because you're printing...

Comment: So you're looking to find the form `ABCDE/FGHIJ = 9`, such that no digits repeat? e.g. `99999/11111 = 9` is right out?

Comment: @WayneWerner No, I mean that A,B,C, etc are _all_ different eg. 98765 / 43210, or something like 62401 / 35978, and checking if it is equal to 9.

Comment: Somewhat similar math puzzle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38393078/difference-between-two-products-nearest-to-zero-non-brute-force-solution/38407302#38407302

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapting Wayne Werner's solution you can do this to add the digit uniqueness constraint (assuming Python 3):

```
[(9*num, num) 
 for num in range(10000, 100000 // 9) 
 if len(set(str(num) + str(num * 9))) == 10]
```

This runs in 1.5 ms on my machine.

Note, that you can only check numbers between 10000 and 100000 / 9 = 11111.

And if you want to allow preceding zeros, you can do it like this:

```
[(9*num, num) 
 for num in range(0, 100000 // 9) 
 if len(set(("%05d" % num) + ("%05d" % (num * 9)))) == 10]
```

And this one takes 15 ms.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how can you tell? The OPs code isn't even valid, at least when copy/pasted

Comment: @WayneWerner going from his description (I didn't even try to go down that nested hell-hole): arrange the digits 0-9 once each so that xx xxx / xx xxx = 9.

Comment: @WayneWerner you're approach of generating numbers that are divisible by 9 was the correct starting point, though.

Comment: Thank you so much. This works perfectly, and I changed the code a bit so that its output is the same as before.

Comment: I just want to know what the "%05d" is, because I didn't understand that part.

Comment: @Tawfeeq This is string-formatting operator: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting Basically, 05 means that the number will be prepended with zeros to get a string of length 5. `"%05d" % num` can also be replaced with a newer `format` method: `"{:05}".format(num)` The docs for that method are here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to use `itertools` for this problem.

```
import itertools

def makenum(digits):
    return int(''.join(map(str, digits)))

for p in itertools.permutations(range(10)):
    a = makenum(p[:5])
    b = makenum(p[5:])
    if a == 9 * b:
        print(a, b)
```

Comment: You can also improve execution time by checking that `a > b`.  I *think* that means that you can stop the first time `b` is greater than `a`.

Comment: @RoadieRich That will improve the execution time only if the definition of `a` and `b` are switched the for loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just want to know now what you did in the _makenum_ function, because I want to understand what I code.

Comment: @RoadieRich Thanks for the idea, but I made my program more complex by allowing the user to change the nine to any number using the input function, so it won't work if the user inputs a number less than 1.

Comment: Okay, I tested the code, and unfortunately, it takes longer (around 80 seconds) to execute. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of algebra:

```
a / b = 9 == a = 9 * b
```

Knowing that, you only have to bother generating the values:

```
[(9*num, num) for num in range(10000, 100000)]
```

If you need to filter things out by some criteria, you can easily write a filter function:

```
def unique_numbers(num):
    num = str(num)
    return len(num) == len(set(num))

[(9*num, num) for num in range(10000, 100000) if unique_numbers(num) and unique_numbers(9*num)]
```

If you wanted to shorten things a bit, you could re-write your function so that it returns the valid pair, or `None` otherwise.

```
def good_nums_or_none(num):
    a = num * 9
    b = num
    str_a = str(a)
    str_b = str(b)
    if len(a) == len(set(a)) and len(b) == len(set(b)):
         return a, b
    else:
         return None

[nums for nums in (good_nums_or_none(num) for num in range(10000, 100000)) if nums is not None]
```

Or, just create a generator and iterate over that:

```
 def target_numbers(factor=9, min=10000, max=100000):
     cur = min
     while cur < max:
         a = factor*cur
         b = cur
         str_a = str(a)
         str_b = str(b)
         if len(a) == len(set(a)) and len(b) == len(set(b)):
             yield a, b

 [num for num in target_numbers()]
```

If you want to allow zero padded numbers in `b` then you can use this filter:

```
def target_numbers(factor=9, min=1000, max=100000):
    cur = min                                      
    while cur < max:                               
        b = cur                                    
        a = factor*cur                             
        text = str(a) + str(b).zfill(5)            
        if len(text) == len(set(text)):            
            yield a, b                             
        cur += 1
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, because first, the number isn't guaranteed to have all different digits, and second, the second number may be smaller than 10000 if it begins with a zero. But thanks for the idea.

Comment: You're missing the critical constraint: the digits of both numbers have to be drawn from (0,1,...,9)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you do realize that's *all* real numbers, right?

Comment: In other words I think you can do this: `[(9*num, num) for num in range(10000, 100000 // 9) if len(set(str(num) + str(num * 9))) == 10]`

Comment: @Tawfeeq I've added a variety of approaches - you weren't terribly clear in your criteria, and `xx xxx` lead me to believe that you want a 5-digit number. If that's not the case, then you can easily change the criteria in any of these functions to specify your ruleset. Granted it will increase the time it takes to run, but it shouldn't take that long. My generator approach only takes ~ 121 ms on my macbook. I suspect slower hardware won't have that much of a problem.

Comment: @WayneWerner sorry if I wasn't clear, but I meant that the numbers a,b have to be natural numbers whose combined digits are drawn from (0,...9) ___without___ replacement. So, for example, 10000 and 90000 are NOT solutions.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You mean duplication. Or repetition. The OP wasn't terribly clear in their problem statement. Regardless, I've added updates that address filtering out duplication.

Comment: @WayneWerner What? No, I meant exactly what I said. Now I'm not sure what you mean. Check your solution. It's giving tons of pairs. There should only be 6 pairs.

Comment: @WayneWerner Check Kolmar's solution.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm confused as to precisely where you're getting your definition. The OPs specific criteria is currently not well defined.

Comment: @WayneWerner I'm getting it precisely from the OP. Look at the first bolded part of the question. It seems pretty unambiguous to me - it's a typical kind of number puzzle, and anyway, it has been clarified in the comments.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga They were asking for factors besides `9` and numbers less than 1. Anyway, I've added code that works for 4 digits in `b`.

Comment: @WayneWerner numbers less than 1??? Look at the OP's response to your question in the Question's comments section.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960714/python-strategically-go-through-ten-digit-numbers-with-0-9/38961088?noredirect=1#comment65276610_38960864

Answer (score 1):

Runs in **0.7 secs**. Faster than most solutions mentioned, though bit clumsy.

```
def sol(a,b,zero):
  for i in range(a,b):
     fl = 0
     marked = 10*[0]
     marked[0] = zero
     tmp = i
     while tmp > 0:
       marked[tmp%10] = marked[tmp%10] + 1
       tmp = tmp/10
     numerator = i*9

     while numerator > 0:
       marked[numerator%10] = marked[numerator%10] + 1
       numerator = numerator/10

     for j in range(10):
        if marked[j] != 1:
           fl = 1

     if fl == 0:
        print "found a solution ",i*9,"/",i


sol(1000,10000,1)
sol(10000,100000,0)
```

The solution printed is:

```
 found a solution  57429 / 6381
 found a solution  58239 / 6471
 found a solution  75249 / 8361
 found a solution  95742 / 10638
 found a solution  95823 / 10647
 found a solution  97524 / 10836
```

Comment: Very nice! I just checked it against brute-force. I'm having a bit of trouble following your logic. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Since this is written in python2, I am unable to test it with python 3. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Tawfeeq it's easily translatable. `print` is a function, use `//` instead of `/`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Two cases (a) if the denominator is a four digit number (b) if the denominator is a five digit number. That's why called the function `sol` two times. For each case I loop through possibilities for denominator. Our numerator is 9*denominator. Then I check that all digits 0-9 are covered exactly once in the decimal representation of numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 0):

This is a minor variation on @David's answer.

If we look at `itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4])`

```
>>> for p in itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4]):
...     print(p)
...
(1, 2, 3, 4)
(1, 2, 4, 3)
(1, 3, 2, 4)
(1, 3, 4, 2)
(1, 4, 2, 3)
(1, 4, 3, 2)
(2, 1, 3, 4)
(2, 1, 4, 3)
(2, 3, 1, 4)
(2, 3, 4, 1)
(2, 4, 1, 3)
(2, 4, 3, 1)
(3, 1, 2, 4)
(3, 1, 4, 2)
(3, 2, 1, 4)
(3, 2, 4, 1)
(3, 4, 1, 2)
(3, 4, 2, 1)
(4, 1, 2, 3)
(4, 1, 3, 2)
(4, 2, 1, 3)
(4, 2, 3, 1)
(4, 3, 1, 2)
(4, 3, 2, 1)
```

You'll notice that for a tuple `(a,b,c,d)`, `(c,d,a,b)` also appears.  If a number `a == 9*b`, then `b != a*9`.  We'll use this to our advantage.

Also, note that if `a = 9*b`, `a` must be bigger than `b`, unless we're using negative numbers or non-integers.

You'll see that as we look at the results, splitting the tuples in half and turning them into numbers gives, initially, a small number followed by a larger number.  This is a side effect of passing `permutations` a sorted list.  Again, we can use this to our advantage.

```
import itertools

def makenum(digits):
    return int(''.join(map(str, digits)))

for p in itertools.permutations(range(10)):
    first_half = makenum(p[:5])    
    second_half = makenum(p[5:])
    if second_half < first_half: # first half is smaller for first half of permutations, second half of permutations has been covered, backwards.
        break
    if second_half == 9 * first_half:
        print(first_half, second_half)
```

If you're taking user input, you should be able to get the same result simply by `sort`ing your input:

```
for p in itertools.permutations(sorted(digits)):
    # ...
```